# An issue with showing that an Iwasawa module has zero $\mu$ invariant

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory

Let $\chi$ denote the $p$-adic cyclotomic character. Let $\mathbb{Q}^{cyc}$ denote the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\gamma$ be the topological generator of $\Gamma=\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}^{cyc}/\mathbb{Q})$ for which $\chi(\gamma)=1+p$. Let $X$ be a finitely generated torsion $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}_p[\Gamma]\simeq \mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ module with $\gamma$ identified with $T+1$.

Suppose that I can show that $\frac{X}{(T+1-\chi^k(\gamma))X}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_p$ module for all $k\equiv 1\mod(p-1)$, does it follow that the $\mu$ invariant of $X$ is zero?

(The issue here is that a finite kernel in a pseudo-isomorphism causes problems).